# How to fix “Operation not supported” on mac os

Tags: macos, terminal, security, external-disk

I am trying to install the Flutter onto my computer onto an external drive I have followed the instructions on their website to try and install it. https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos. I can download it then unzip it, but when I try and run any flutter command it gives me an "Operation not supported" error infinite amount of times.

I have tried to install it on my desktop and it worked just fine. The problem is something with the external hard drive. The directory I have tried to install flutter in is /Volumes/RAVPOWER/Devins_Macbook/flutter_development I have added this to my paths folder, I have also tried adding it to .bash_profile. When I run the echo command it shows me exactly where the path to flutter is flutter_development/flutter/bin.

I have also tried changing the permissions for the /Volumes folder I set the users to my name and set it to 777. it has a + at the end of the permissions for the folder I don't know if that makes a difference, but I also don't know how to get rid of it.

I have also set full disk access to terminal first, then I set full disk access to the flutter exec.

I haven't tried running mac in recovery mode because that would only be a temporary fix if I messed with the sip settings and disabled it

I have been dealing with this issue for a while and I'd like to do all my development on this drive as it is the only thing I have space on. any help would be apreciated

```
shlock: link(/Volumes/RAVPOWER/Devins_Macbook/flutter_development/flutter/bin/cache/shlock1241, /Volumes/RAVPOWER/Devins_Macbook/flutter_development/flutter/bin/cache/.upgrade_lock): Operation not supported
```

the number after shlock is how many times its tried to run I am not sure what .upgrade_lock running the ls -al command

```
drwxr-xr-x   8 devintripp  admin    256 Dec 15  2018 Users
drwxrwxrwx+  6 devintripp  wheel    192 Nov  7 20:51 Volumes
```

as you can see the Users has less permissions than the actual drive

The expected results should tell me what I need to install for flutter to work on my computer as flutter doctor should.